# How to display multiple view bags into Html text control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am struck in below trouble.

i am getting values into view bag but I cant combine it one view bag or cant bind three individual viewbags to html text control.

*/Code side*/

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

     var studentFName = (from p in db.Student_Registration
                               where p.Registration_Id == studentIds
                               select p.Student_First_Name).SingleOrDefault();
     var studentMName = (from p in db.Student_Registration
                                where p.Registration_Id == studentIds
                                select p.Student_Middle_Name).SingleOrDefault();
     var studentLName = (from p in db.Student_Registration
                                where p.Registration_Id == studentIds
                                select p.Student_Last_Name).SingleOrDefault();

     ViewBag.studentFName = studentFName;
     ViewBag.studentMName = studentMName;
     ViewBag.studentLName = studentLName;

                               (OR)

     string StudentName = Convert.ToString(studentFName) + " " + Convert.ToString(studentMName) + " " + Convert.ToString(studentLName);

     ViewBag.StudentName  = StudentName ;
     return View((Student_Marks_Table)editmodel);
}
```

/* View side */

```
$('<span>Student Name</span><br/><div style="width:350px;"><input type="text" id="Student_Name" style="width:250px;" name="Student_Name" value=@ViewBag.studentFName @ViewBag.studentMName @ViewBag.studentLName /></div>')
                                  (OR)
 $('<span>Student Name</span><br/><div style="width:350px;"><input type="text" id="Student_Name" style="width:250px;" name="Student_Name" value=@ViewBag.studentName/></div>')
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing ?

Comment: There are missing the `"` at the beginning and the end of `value`

Comment: Typical homework scenario... And why are you running the same query three times? Why are you doing `Convert.ToString()` on values that are most likely strings already? (Okay, perhaps they are null... but there are better ways to deal with that) What is `Student_Marks_Table`? What is `editModel`? And if you are using an editModel to call the View, why aren't you using `Model` inside the View?

Comment: I just necessary code pasted here so in that quotes are given but still not getting values

Comment: and one more thing..I did it by two three ways, thats why converted and unconvert values used..

Comment: Student_Marks_Table is a databse table name

Comment: not error.. I cant see viewbag value into text control in browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('<span>Student Name</span><br/><div style="width:350px;"><input type="text" id="Student_Name" style="width:250px;" name="Student_Name" value="@ViewBag.StudentName"/></div>')
```

I see you are not using @ViewBag.StudentName instead @ViewBag.studentName, c# is case sensitive, make sure you are aware of it

Comment: I just necessary code pasted here so in that same given but still not getting values

Comment: do you still have issue?

Comment: no sir, now its completed ..reason is forgot to give double quotes.